# Unable to install most Bluemix CF plugins

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-plugin

Attempting to install plugins from the [Bluemix Plugin Repository](http://plugins.ng.bluemix.net/ui/repository.html) using the latest cf client:

```
cf version 6.14.0+2654a47-2015-11-18
```

on both Mac OSX and Centos 7, I get the following error when attempting an install from the repo (the following are from the Centos machine):

```
[michael@oracle ~]$ cf install-plugin -r bluemix vpn

Attention: Plugins are binaries written by potentially untrusted authors. Install and use plugins at your own risk.

Do you want to install the plugin vpn? (y or n)> y
Looking up 'vpn' from repository 'bluemix'
9741777 bytes downloaded...
FAILED
Downloaded plugin binary's checksum does not match repo metadata
```

Downloading the binary plugin and attempting a local install, gives me:

```
cf install-plugin bluemix-admin-linux_x64

Attention: Plugins are binaries written by potentially untrusted authors. Install and use plugins at your own risk.

Do you want to install the plugin bluemix-admin-linux_x64? (y or n)> y

Installing plugin ./bluemix-admin-linux_x64...
FAILED
exit status 127
```

Further examination yields:

```
ldd bluemix-admin-linux_x64
./bluemix-admin-linux_x64: error while loading shared libraries: ./bluemix-admin-linux_x64: unsupported version 6773 of Verneed record
```

While this example is for the vpn plugin, all plugins besides IBM-Containers yield the same results on a remote install attempt (the checksum error) and some variation in examining the binary itself, for instance with active_deploy:

```
ldd active-deploy-linux-amd64-0.1.67
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc649d4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000036a0a00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000369fe00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000369fa00000)
```

I've not seen this with other community Cloud Foundry plugins so this phenomenon seems unique to how these plugins are being generated by IBM.   Any suggestions or thoughts on how I could resolve this myself (a source repo that I could compile these myself, while unfortunate, would suffice at this point).

Tks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this container, it has cf and container plugin installed already:
https://hub.docker.com/r/reachlin/bluemix/

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, I had been trying to get the vpn plugin to work and this one was the plugin for containers.  The good news is I can get inside the container and adding the vpn plugin works just fine, so at least this is a workaround until the plugin can install natively.

Docker saves the day once again.

Comment: Using docker for plugins like vpn or active-deploy is ok, but you won't be able to do a `cf push` from the docker cf. Unless you install another native cf-client to do this for you (and let's be fair, that's an ugly workaround), it will become a problem when you'll want to script your deployment...

Comment: @Sebastien, actually you can do docker image push or pull using this container with the hack to mount docker socket on host to the container

Comment: I found another workaround, using the docker -v option to mount the wanted folders. Create your container like this: `docker run --name bluemix -v /home/user:/home/user -d --privileged reachlin/bluemix`. You can then create a script into /usr/bin/cf that does basically `args="$@"` and then `docker exec bluemix "cd $PWD && cf $args"`. You can then push everything located in your home directory and use it as a regular cf client.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the official CLI for Bluemix is the cloud Foundry CLI as described on Bluemix doc pages

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/downloads.html

I think your errors are depending from your error in referring the plugin.

Checking the doc page for cf vpn plugin for Bluemix
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/plugins/vpn/index.html

you have to specify the plugin version you downloaded (and right for your own environment) and not only 'vpn'

For MS Windows OS:

cf install-plugin vpn_windows64.exe

For Apple MAC OS:

cf install-plugin vpn_mac_os_amd64

For Linux OS:

cf install-plugin vpn_linuxamd64

You could also configure bluemix plugin repository as cf repository and then install the plugins choosing it as source repository.

Comment: I think I addressed that in the first sentence:

__using the latest cf client__

Comment: Sorry, confused by link reference  followed, I edited my answer

Comment: Again, this is mentioned directly in my question.  One way you'd install a plugin would be from the repo, where you use the canonical name.  Just as a test, I did try:

`cf install-plugin -r bluemix-repo vpn_linuxamd64`

which of course didn't work as expected.  Repeating from my original question, I'd also downloaded the binary for my platform and attempted a local install (it's a good 2/3 of the entire question).  

Rest assured that I've read the instructions with a fine tooth comb, I've spun a new VM up, I've tried in a docker container, windows, OSX.